# Duplicate Primary keys getting generated while Inserting record using EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, task

I am facing a strange problem. when i am inserting record into a table with primary key as identity already defined , new record is inserted with Id 1 always. I am lost as to why it is happening. Integrity is lost if there are duplicate primary keys in the table.

[image]

this is the table structure

[image]

Is the issue arising due to having different contexts inside the transaction.
I am inserting points into different tables on different user activity. So for 1 activity multiple users can get points which will be inserted into multiple tables and for saving the points i have created multiple tasks.

this is one of the method which is getting called

```
   public async Task<MethodResult> AddPointsForPollVote(int UserId, int PollOptionId)
    {

       using (var transaction = _entities.Database.BeginTransaction())
       {
           try
           {
               var PostId = await GetPostMasterIdFromOption((int)GamificationItemType.Poll, PollOptionId);
               var PostOwner = await GetOwnerOfThePost((int)GamificationItemType.Poll, PostId);
               var OptionOwner = await GetOwnerOfThePostOptions((int)GamificationItemType.Poll, PollOptionId);
               List<int> tagIds = _entities.PollTags.Where(x => x.Id == PostId).Select(x => x.TagId).ToList();

                List<Task> lst = new List<Task>();

               if (await CheckIfDailyPointLimitExceded((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, UserId) == false) // User limit not exceeded
               {
                   // Add Daily Activity Point For User
                   var DailyActivityResultForUser = AddDailyActivityPointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, (int)GamificationItemType.Poll, UserId);
                   lst.Add(DailyActivityResultForUser);

                   // Add Total Redeemable Point For User
                   var TotalRedeemablePointsForUser = AddOrUpdateTotalRedeemablePointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, UserId);
                   lst.Add(TotalRedeemablePointsForUser);


                   // Add Total Point For User
                   var TotalPointsForUser = AddOrUpdateTotalPointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, UserId);
                   lst.Add(TotalPointsForUser);

                    // Add Topic Points For User
                    var TopicPointsForUser = AddOrUpdatePointsForTags((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, tagIds, UserId);
                    lst.Add(TopicPointsForUser);

                    // Add Topic points For maintaining User Level 
                    var TopicPointLevelForUser = AddOrUpdatePointsLevelForTags((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, tagIds, UserId);
                    lst.Add(TopicPointLevelForUser);

                    // Add Daily Topic points For user 
                    var DailyTopicPointLevelForUser = AddDailyTopicWisePoints((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_User, tagIds, UserId);
                    lst.Add(DailyTopicPointLevelForUser);
                }

               if (await CheckIfDailyPointLimitExceded((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner, OptionOwner) == false) // Option Owners limit not exceeded
               {
                   // Add Daily Activity Point to  Option Owner
                   var DailyActivityResultForOptionOwner = AddDailyActivityPointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner,(int)GamificationItemType.Poll,OptionOwner);
                   lst.Add(DailyActivityResultForOptionOwner);


                   // Add Total Redeemable Point to Option Owner
                   var TotalRedeemablePointsForOptionOwner = AddOrUpdateTotalRedeemablePointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner, OptionOwner);
                   lst.Add(TotalRedeemablePointsForOptionOwner);

                   // Add Total Point to Option Owner
                   var TotalPointsForOptionOwner = AddOrUpdateTotalPointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner, OptionOwner);
                   lst.Add(TotalPointsForOptionOwner);

                    // Add Topic Points For Option owner
                    var TopicPointsForOptionOwner = AddOrUpdatePointsForTags((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner, tagIds, OptionOwner);
                    lst.Add(TopicPointsForOptionOwner);

                    // Add Topic points For maintaining Option Owner Level 
                    var TopicPointLevelForOptionOwner = AddOrUpdatePointsLevelForTags((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner, tagIds, OptionOwner);
                    lst.Add(TopicPointLevelForOptionOwner);

                    // Add Daily Topic points For Option Owner 
                    var DailyTopicPointLevelForOptionOwner = AddDailyTopicWisePoints((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Option_Owner, tagIds, OptionOwner);
                    lst.Add(DailyTopicPointLevelForOptionOwner);
                }


               if (await CheckIfDailyPointLimitExceded((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, PostOwner) == false) // Post Owners limit not exceeded
               {
                   // Add Daily Activity Point to Post Owner
                   var DailyActivityResultForPollOwner = AddDailyActivityPointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, (int)GamificationItemType.Poll,PostOwner);
                   lst.Add(DailyActivityResultForPollOwner);


                   // Add Total Redeemable Point to Post Owner
                   var TotalRedeemablePointsForPostOwner = AddOrUpdateTotalRedeemablePointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, PostOwner);
                   lst.Add(TotalRedeemablePointsForPostOwner);


                   // Add Total Point to Post Owner
                   var TotalPointsForPollOwner = AddOrUpdateTotalPointsForUser((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, PostOwner);
                   lst.Add(TotalPointsForPollOwner);


                    // Add Topic Points For Post owner
                    var TopicPointsForPostOwner = AddOrUpdatePointsForTags((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, tagIds, PostOwner);
                    lst.Add(TopicPointsForPostOwner);


                    // Add Topic points For maintaining Post Owner Level 
                    var TopicPointLevelForPostOwner = AddOrUpdatePointsLevelForTags((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, tagIds, PostOwner);
                    lst.Add(TopicPointLevelForPostOwner);


                    // Add Daily Topic points For Post Owner 
                    var DailyTopicPointLevelForPostOwner = AddDailyTopicWisePoints((int)GamificationUserActions.Poll_Vote_Points_To_Poll_Owner, tagIds, PostOwner);
                    lst.Add(DailyTopicPointLevelForPostOwner);
                }


               await Task.WhenAll(lst);


               transaction.Commit();

               return new MethodResult() { Success = true, Message = "Points Added !!" };
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               transaction.Rollback();
               return new MethodResult() { Success = false, Message = "There was some error !!" };
           }
       }


    }
```

this is one of the method that i being called which is used to insert data into the table

```
 public async Task AddDailyActivityPointsForUser(int ActionId, int ItemId, int UserId)
    {

        using (var context = new Entities())
        {

            try
            {
                DailyActivityPoint dailyActivityPoint = new DailyActivityPoint()
                {
                    ActionId = ActionId,
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ItemId = ItemId,
                    UserId = UserId,
                    PointsAccumulated = await GetPointsAwardedForAction(ActionId)
                };

                context.DailyActivityPoints.Add(dailyActivityPoint);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog errorLog = new ErrorLog()
                {
                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ErrorMessage = ex.Message,
                    ModuleName = "GamificationPointsService",
                    CustomMessage = " Error while Adding Daily Activity Points For user : AddDailyActivityPointsForUser ActionId : " + ActionId + " , ItemId : " + ItemId + " , UserId : " + UserId,
                    stackTrace = ex.StackTrace
                };

                context.ErrorLogs.Add(errorLog);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

        }


    }
```

As you can see 6 methods are being called 3 times inside the transaction and transaction commits when i have awaited all of them.
Duplicate primary key is getting inserted for some tables only. Rest are working fine.
But question is howcome sql is allowing duplicate primary key.

Please Guide me. What can be the issue. Is it the way i have coded this [Bad practise or something , this is the first time i am using tasks and async programming [newbee :p]] ??

Table script :

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Gamification].[DailyActivityPoints](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PointsAccumulated] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Gamification].[DailyActivityPoints] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate())        FOR [CreatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Gamification].[DailyActivityPoints]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ActionId]) REFERENCES [Gamification].[ActionMaster] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Gamification].[DailyActivityPoints]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ItemId]) REFERENCES [Gamification].[ItemType] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Gamification].[DailyActivityPoints]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
GO
```

Comment: If you manage to violate a unique primary key constraint there's something seriously wrong with the database itself. It's irrelevant how the data are inserted. Why doesn't the table have a clustered index? How did you create it?

Comment: but what could it be ?? And why only for certain tables out of multiple tables in which data is inserted !!!... Stuck bigtime here ....

Comment: This can only happen if the index on `Id` isn't unique, or disabled, AND records are inserted with `identity_insert` on. Check the insert SQL queries.

Comment: As i am using Entity framework , as far as i know by default identity insert is off. Also while inserting the data itself i am not passing the value of the Id.  
Intresting thing that i found just now was if i am trying to delete the records i can't.
As you can see in the first image all the records have Id=1 when i am trying to delete records with id 1 i get 0 rows affected !!! strange...

Comment: I am using EF6 in my WebAPI2 project

Comment: I think you should rebuild/re-create the indexes, maybe run DBCC CHECKDB first to see if anything is corrupt. What about the other suggestions I did?

Comment: INDEX is unique , i checked and identity insert is definitely off.  I am running CheckDB to see if there are any issues..

Comment: @user1063760, I suspect SSMS Object Explorer isn't reflecting current reality. Right-click on the table, script as create, and add that DDL to your question.

Comment: Edited the post to accomodate DDL of the table.

Comment: Well, something is different in the table you show in the image, because the PK index isn't clustered while in the DDL it is.